# BrowserSync to inject css into a live Wordpress page via proxy

Tags: css, wordpress, browser-sync

I am trying to use BrowserSync & sass to edit the style.css from a Wordpress site.
I'd like to inject the changes into the page and reload it automatically.

So far I tried a lot of variants to the gulpfile.js code without success -- the scss files compile into style.css (ok), but the page doesn't reflect the changes.

Here is my code:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    bs   = require('browser-sync');

// -- sass
//
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp
        .src('src/scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({ includePaths: [ 'src/scss/include' ] }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('wp-content/themes/my-theme'))
        .pipe(bs.reload({ stream: true }));
});

// -- serve
//
gulp.task('serve', [ 'sass' ], function() {

    bs({
        proxy: "http://my-site.com",
        files: "wp-content/themes/my-theme/style.css"
    });

    gulp.watch( "src/scss/**/*.scss", ['sass'] );
});
```

For the moment, I resorted to use the awkward Chrome workspace override, but the workflow is not as smooth as it could be.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you typed gulp watch from the command line in the directory you want monitored for changes?

Comment: Hi Joe, 
I added a line in the 'serve' task, that seem redundant with the sass task, with no result:

    gulp.watch( "wp-content/themes/my-theme/style.css", bs.reload({ stream: true }) );

Comment: @Multicam did any styles change? I'm trying to achieve the same at the moment. I'll add an answer if I solve or update here with tips.